# javascript execute function after multiple asynchronous function calls

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to call a function after multiple requests are sent out. The `loadEventsFromCalendar` function sends out requests for accessing the event data for each calendar and then stores it into `json_event_list`. The `renderTimeline` function take this big list and draws a visualization based on that.

```
function loadFromAllCalendars(calendarNames){
    var dfd_lst=[];
    //Load events from all selected calendars
    for (var i =0; i<calendarNames.length;i++){
        dfd_lst.push(loadEventsFromCalendar(calendarNameIds[calendarNames[i]],calendarNames[i]));
    }
    $.when.apply($,dfd_lst).done(renderTimeline);
}

  function loadEventsFromCalendar(calendarId,calendarName) {
    var dfd = $.Deferred();
    // Add events from calendar corresponding to the given calendarId into json_event_lst. 
    var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
      'calendarId': calendarId,
      'timeMin': startdate.toISOString(),
      'showDeleted': false,
      'singleEvents': true,
      'maxResults': 50,
      'orderBy': 'startTime'
    });
    request.execute(function(resp) {
      ....data processing of json_event...
      json_event_lst.push(json_event)
      dfd.resolve();
      return dfd.promise()
    });
  }
```

I have tried using a jquery deferred object to check if the promises are met, but the renderTimeline function still gets called before the data array is populated.

```
function loadFromAllCalendars(calendarNames){
    var dfd_lst=[];
    //Load events from all selected calendars
    for (var i =0; i<calendarNames.length;i++){
dfd_lst.push(loadEventsFromCalendar(calendarNameIds[calendarNames[i]],calendarNames[i]));
    }
    $.when.apply($,dfd_lst).done(renderTimeline);
}
```

Comment: Does `renderTimeline` expect a parameter to be passed?

Answer (score 0):

Use promise `all()` to wait until several promises are resolved.

```
Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The deferred object methods didn't quite work because even if the request wasn't executed (i.e. no return in the function), an undefined value is then stored into the dfd_lst, which somehow makes the `.done` gets executed. I ended up resolving this issue by adding an additional Boolean parameter `renderVis` in `loadEventsFromCalendar` to specify whether to render or not:

```
function loadEventsFromCalendar(calendarId,calendarName,renderVis=false) {
    // Add events from calendar corresponding to the given calendarId into json_event_lst. 
    var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
      'calendarId': calendarId,
      'timeMin': startdate.toISOString(),
      'showDeleted': false,
      'singleEvents': true,
      'maxResults': 50,
      'orderBy': 'startTime'
    });

    request.execute(function(resp){
        ....
        ....
        if (renderVis){
            renderTimeline();
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: The solution was to not use `$.when()`, `$.Deferred()`, `deferred.done()`?

Comment: yeah, the Boolean parameter was a workaround that didn't require the use of a deferred object.

Comment: How is Answer related to actual `javascript` at Question where `$.when()`, `$.Deferred()` are used?